# Save Array via ORMLite in Android without foreign key/table

Tags: android, ormlite

I have Object

```
public class PhotoEntity {

    @SerializedName("users_mentioned")
    @DatabaseField(???)
    public ArrayList<Integer> mentions = new ArrayList<>();

    // Other fields

}
```

I need to store Photo, but **how i need to mark my `mentions` list**?

> Note: I use **Gson** for parsing object, so the **structure must be saved**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom persister for the field:

```java
public class PhotoEntity {
    @SerializedName("users_mentioned")
    @DatabaseField(persisterClass = SerializableCollectionsType.class)
    public ArrayList<Integer> mentions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The persister requires a singleton but it's very simple:

```
public class SerializableCollectionsType extends SerializableType {

    private static SerializableCollectionsType singleton;

    private SerializableCollectionsType() {
        super(SqlType.SERIALIZABLE, new Class<?>[0]);
    }

    // ormLite requires a getSingleton() method
    public static SerializableCollectionsType getSingleton() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            synchronized (SerializableCollectionsType.class) {
                if (singleton == null) {
                    singleton = new SerializableCollectionsType();
                }
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValidForField(Field field) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's not possible to store array in sqlite row, you need foreign table to store that.

but if you keep wanted to store the array without foreign table, i suggest that you store json in string to sqlite database.

```
public class PhotoEntity {

    @SerializedName("users_mentioned")
    @DatabaseField
    public String mentions;

    // Other fields

}
```

so when you storing the mentions list you should store it as json string

```
List<Mention> mentions = new ArrayList<>();
mentions.add(new Mention());
String jsonMentions = new Gson().toJson(mentions);
PhotoEntity photoEntity = new PhotoEntity();
photoEntity.setMentions(jsonMentions);
```